# ParseFile : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
  router.post('/uploadImage',function(req,res){
  console.log("Upload image called");
  var dcod=req.body.myPhoto;
  console.log("File : "+req.body.myPhoto+"\n"+dcod);

  var file = {base64:dcod};
  var decodedFile = new Buffer(file, 'base64');
  var name ="a.jpg";

  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name,decodedFile,"image/jpg");
    parseFile.save().then(function() 
           {
              console.log("inside save");
              Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
              var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
              query.equalTo("objectId","S8qZJM7XIA");
              query.find({
                success: function(results) 
                {
                 results.set("profileImg",parseFile);
                 results.save(null, {
                   success: function(results) {
                   params.success(Response.UpdateSuccess);
                   },
                   error: function(gameScore, error) {
                       console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                       }
                   });
                }
              })
           }, 
           function(error) 
           {
             console.log("error  :"+error.message);
           }
    );
});
```

I am getting an error while saving the image to my Object in Parse Cloud.

In `parseFile.save()then(.....)`

throws error at runtime.
I.e.,

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: So parseFile is undefined for some reason.  What is your question?

Comment: Hi mam ,I am getting error in ParseFile,Actully i want to save Image to Parse.com,but it showing error while type casting from image to file i.e  var parseFile = new Parse.File("a.JPEG",{base64: new Buffer(req.body.uploadImage).toString('base64')});